# Is this site not suited for web scraping using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I try to use beautifulsoup to get the odds for each match on the following site:

https://danskespil.dk/oddset/sports/category/990/counter-strike-go/matches

The goal is to end up with some kind of text file containing the following:

Match1, Team1, Odds for team1 winning, Team2, Odds for team2 winning

Match2, Team1, Odds for team1 winning, Team2, Odds for team2 winning

and so on...

I am new to beautifulsoup so things already go wrong at a very elementary level. My approach is to "walk" through the html tree until I arrive in a div tag, where I can see all the matches are contained. This works well until hit a div tag with class="sgd-wrapper", there is a link below to see a picture for clarification.

[This picture is for clarification.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjU3y.png)

The following is my code, and neither m1 or m2 works. Python just responses with none.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests as res

#Load the webpage content
r = res.get('https://danskespil.dk/oddset/sports/category/990/counter-strike-go/matches').text

#Convert to a beautiful soup object
soup = bs(r,'lxml')

m1 = soup.find("div", attrs={"id": "wrapper"}).find("div", attrs={"class": "page-box"}).find("div", attrs={"class": "page-area"}).find("div", attrs={"id": "oddset-nashville"}).find("div", attrs={"class": "sgd-wrapper"})
m2 = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "sgd-wrapper"})
```

If I remove the last find in m1 or redefine m2

```
m1 = soup.find("div", attrs={"id": "wrapper"}).find("div", attrs={"class": "page-box"}).find("div", attrs={"class": "page-area"}).find("div", attrs={"id": "oddset-nashville"})
m2 = soup.find("div", attrs={"id": "oddset-nashville"})
```

Then I get the response

```
print(m1)
<div data-digital-portal-loader-url="https://assets.sb.danskespil.dk/front-end/digitalPortal.js?noCache=20201011001813" id="oddset-nashville"></div>
```

Can someone explain me why this div class="sgd-wrapper" is so special?

Comment: The page is generated on the fly, so look at using selenium to scape this site.  Instead of using Inspect look at the View Source, which has different HTML.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is at the line with `r = res.get('https://danskespil.dk/oddset/sports/category/990/counter-strike-go/matches').text`

Python requests library just sent your HTTP/HTTPS request to the server and get the raw html and it does not help you to load more resources like pictures and scripts, which means that some elements is manipulate in javascript scripts (for example, create an element, set class name and insert into DOM tree):

another example, if you `GET` main.html via requests, it does not load `main.js` and the class of div `t1` will not be set as `sgd-wrapper`

```
# main.html
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="t1"></div>
      <script src="main.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>

# in main.js
document.querySelector('#t1').classList.add('sgd-wrapper');
```

what you need to do is to use headless Chrome (like `google-chorme --headless` to launch Chrome) and use Chrome API to hook on page loading events then dump whole complete contents.